# How to collapse a pop-up when you click somewhere else

Tags: javascript, click

I have custom form like element made with javascript. It works a bit like the HTML select. I.e. clicking on its pull-down control displays a pop-up of options and when you click on an option, the pop-up collapses.

I would also like to collapse the pop-up when you click somewhere else on the page. E.g. another control. At the moment I have a click event attached to the body element to do this, but it doesnt seem like the correct way to do it. Any suggestions for a better way to detect when to collapse the pop-up?

Comment: Could you show us the code you have now, or possibly a jsfiddle?

Comment: you could add the click handler on `body` when the popup is opened, then remove it when the popup is closed (`body.onclick = null`). nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It's hard to provide an answer with no example code. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=close+popup+click+outside

Comment: sorry cant provide code. I was hoping for an answer to the general question on how to handle this kind of thing. Thanks for the link, it seems that just having it on 'body' is the way to go.